# How to fix 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',)' in ubuntu terminal?

Tags: python

I am new to python and ubuntu. I was trying to download data from synapse. About 30% was downloaded and I left the pc ON for the night. The next morning this is what I saw,

This is for an ubuntu server

My code to download :

```
import synapseclient

syn = synapseclient.Synapse()
syn.login('gaurangk','tennisbat')

# Obtain a pointer and download the data
syn18507661 = syn.get(entity='syn18507661')

# Get the path to the local copy of the data file
filepath = syn18507661.path
```

This is the complete error code,

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "ok.py", line 7, in 
>       syn18507661 = syn.get(entity='syn18507661')
>     File "/home/abhinav/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/synapseclient/client.py", line 633, in get
>       return self._getWithEntityBundle(entityBundle=bundle, entity=entity, **kwargs)
>     File "/home/abhinav/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/synapseclient/client.py", line 749, in _getWithEntityBundle
>       self._download_file_entity(downloadLocation, entity, ifcollision, submission)
>     File "/home/abhinav/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/synapseclient/client.py", line 807, in _download_file_entity
>       downloadPath = self._downloadFileHandle(entity.dataFileHandleId, objectId, objectType, downloadPath)
>     File "/home/abhinav/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/synapseclient/client.py", line 1755, in _downloadFileHandle
>       raise exc_info0
>   requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='file-prod.prod.sagebase.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /file/v1/fileHandle/batch (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',)))
>   .....

Comment: check see how long it takes your login session gets expire. maybe you need to login again after amount of time.

Comment: check this linke too https://sagebionetworks.jira.com/browse/SYNPY-296?workflowName=Default%20Workflow&stepId=6 . there is a bug for upload/download large files in some versions.